# What is the opposite of Wine?

Tags: windows, linux, emulation

What if I want to run native Unix-like applications on Windows?  What's the best application out there?

Comment: nah, that would be the successor of wine...;)

Comment: WTF.. these comments are very funny

Comment: I'm surprised no one has said "dual-booting" yet.

Comment: I'm amazed "cheese" hasn't shown up yet!

Comment: Vinegar (what happens to Wine when it goes off).
Champagne (what some people think is better than Wine - yuck!)

Answer (score 25, accepted):

[Cygwin](http://cygwin.org/) is closest to what you are looking for, though not **exactly** like Wine.

> Cygwin is a Linux-like environment for Windows. It consists of two parts:
>
> 1. A DLL (cygwin1.dll) which acts as a Linux API emulation layer providing substantial Linux API functionality.
> 2. A collection of tools which provide Linux look and feel.

It is not binary-compatible with Linux applications, you still need to rebuild them from source to run under Cygwin. Once rebuilt, however, they should work exactly like on Linux.

Comment: Thanks to open source products, I've never needed binary compatibility.  If there isn't a pre-built package, just grab source and compile.

Comment: @Ericson, A pre-built package doesn't need to be compiled.  It's already compiled.  That's what "pre-build" means.  =]

Comment: @strager: Huh? I mean if someone else hasn't built a package for Cygwin (and that's somewhat rare), I can normally get what I want by building the source myself.  I don't care about binary compatibility at all.  Your comment does not compute.

Comment: You could also mention SUA, being included in the larger Vista, 2k8 and Win7 editions.

Comment: @Ericson, Ah, sorry.  I am tired.  I misread your comment completely.  My mistake...  Disregard my comment.  ;P

Comment: -1, Sorry but even if it does resolve the porobleme of yoitsfrancis. It is not a accurate answer for question (what is the opposite of wine?). Although it is a good workaround.

Comment: @Phong, so... does this mean you have a better solution? I did state that it's not the exact equivalent.

Comment: Just like other said: there is virtualbox, vmware, coLinux... It is not that I dont like your answer, but I think that exact answer for the question should be in higher rank than a workaround. (For the people who are looking for the same answer)

Answer (score 14):

Not quite the same, but you could also run a full linux installation inside a VM such as Virtualbox: http://virtualbox.org/

Comment: Why the downvote?  Cygwin is not always the right answer for all situations.  A virtual machine can be a good alternative.

Comment: This is cheating though.  You're not really running the applications "on Windows" anymore.

Comment: Oh, I readily admit it's not the same, hence I said "Not quite the same,"  :-D  However, depending on what the end goal is, it may be perfectly acceptable. Often, people don't know what's possible, so don't know exactly what to ask. So, I offer an alternative :)

Comment: At the end of the day, having tried many different ways of using unix tools on a windows system, I have just simply found that the best answer is a virtualization answer.

Answer (score 14):

Take a look at [andLinux](http://www.andlinux.org/) (based on [coLinux](http://www.colinux.org/)).

From the site:

> andLinux is a complete Ubuntu Linux
>   system running seamlessly in Windows
>   2000 based systems (2000, XP, 2003,
>   Vista; 32-bit versions only).
>
> ...
>
> Although this technology is a bit like
>   running Linux in a virtual machine,
>   coLinux differs itself by being more
>   of a merger of Windows and the Linux
>   kernel and not an emulated PC, making
>   it more efficient. Xming is used as X
>   server and PulseAudio as sound server.
>
> andLinux is not just for development
>   and runs almost all Linux applications
>   without modification.

Comment: Amazing you have no comments - coLinux is a really neat idea.

Answer (score 9):

**Not** [Cygwin.](http://cygwin.org/)

> What Isn't Cygwin?
>
> - Cygwin is **not** a way to run native linux apps on Windows. *You have to rebuild your application from source if you want it to run on Windows.*
> - Cygwin is **not** a way to magically make native Windows apps aware of UNIX ® functionality, like signals, ptys, etc. Again, you need to build your apps from source if you want to take advantage of Cygwin functionality.

Cygwin will give a Linux-like shell but can not directly run linux applications in Windows. Cygwin **"acts as a Linux API emulation layer providing substantial Linux API functionality."**

Comment: This doesn't provide an answer to the original question.  It's more like a combative response to @Checkers' answer.

Comment: In other words, Cygwin is more like Winelib than it is like Wine.

Comment: I dont agree with you Rob, In wine you dont need to recompile windows application.

Answer (score 5):

At one point in the distant past, there was [LINE Is Not an Emulator](http://sourceforge.net/projects/line/), which aimed to be exactly the inverse of Wine: provide binary compatibility for Linux executables running under Windows.

It kinda worked, at least as a proof of concept, but there isn't a big need for it.

Answer (score 4):

If you're interested in porting those *nix applications to a Win32 environment, you might take a look at the [MinGW](http://www.mingw.org/) project.  I've mainly used it for GCC on windows, but they also provide an interesting environment called MSYS:

> A Minimal SYStem providing a POSIX
>   compatible Bourne shell environment,
>   with a small collection of UNIX
>   command line tools. Primarily
>   developed as a means to execute the
>   configure scripts and Makefiles used
>   to build Open Source software, but
>   also useful as a general purpose
>   command line interface to replace
>   Windows cmd.exe.

Comment: I like it, but beware of path name mangling, it can mess up makefiles designed for Cygwin.

Answer (score 3):

Microsoft, for a while, offered [SFU](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/interopmigration/bb380242.aspx) which sort of works for some things.  Cygwin works much better.

If you're hoping for ABI Compatability, as wine offers unix systems for windows binaries, things are quite bleak.  [CoLinux](http://www.colinux.org/) also sort of works, but generally won't help you at all with any kind of graphical application, unless you configure a windows X11 server as well.

Comment: Xming is freely available, albeit slow. But works well for basic things.

Comment: @Johannes Rossel: This should perhaps be an answer to the question, instead of a comment?

Answer (score 1):

I've used [andLinux](http://andlinux.org) which is built on [coLinux](http://www.colinux.org/).  The organization has compiled an Ubuntu installation (Gutsy, I think, but I upgraded to Intrepid pretty easily).

One warning: development on andLinux is pretty slow -- the last beta has been out for almost a year.